# How to set the Identity that website runs under

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a wordpress site that connects to Sql Server using the Sql Server PHP driver on IIS 7.  I now want to set up Windows Authentication to connect with.

I know how to do this on the Sql Server side, but I don't know how to configure the account that the website will connect with.

Right now, when I try to connect to Sql Server, this is the message it gives: [SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'  So it is obviously trying to connect using IUSR.

So how do I set the User Account that it will connect with?

Greg

Comment: using windows authentication means connecting with the user the connecting app runs under, right? That is IUSR for IIS, so I would say not possible to change, unless you want to change the user IIS is running under?

Comment: The idea is to set the user that the website is running under, so I can then add that identity to Sql Server so I can give it specific permissions to do what it needs.